Medieval 2000s comedy rated R
I will tell you everything that i know..

this movie was released between 2005-2008. i think it was 2006 but i'm not sure.
its a comedy movie set in medieval Britain or France.
the evil king marries a girl and her boyfriend fights him in the end.
there is a scene in which the boyfriend is in a church and he is sitting in a big bathtub and 2 nuns come and have sex with him. (i think he was dreaming i'm not sure) 
in the end when the king and the boyfriend fight. there is a big well i think on which they are both fighting with swords. 
i think it was a british movie but can also be a hollywood movie .

please reply if you know the name of this movie

This sounds like the plot of Virgin Territory from 2007 with Hayden Christensen and Mischa Barton which was a sort of Medieval American Pie, though I think it's a count there, not a king. From Wiki:

The film is set in Tuscany during the Black Death. As in the Decameron, ten young Florentines take refuge from the plague. But instead of telling stories, they have lusty adventures, bawdy exchanges, romance and swordplay. 

There's a scene there with a guy taking a bath with two nuns, who also appear in the trailer:




yes. thank you. really appreciate it.
